# What's the difference between creating a report in BI publisher and creating a report using a BI administrator repository?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, obiee, bi-publisher

I've been trying to build a repository using the BI administrator tool in OBIEE. The repository is then loaded using the enterprise manager without any issues. But a new analysis could not be performed because of the following error whenever I try to see the answers of my analysis in the analytics presentation port 9704:

**Message returned from OBIS. [nQSError: 42016] Check database specific features table. Must be able to push at least a single table reference to a remote database (HY000)**

which I haven't been able to correct. Then I came across a link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TK7KYaCEGZU

which creates a report using the BI publisher. It has the features I want:
1. I am able to access my table in the Oracle server
2. I choose the columns and make it into a data model
3. I use this model to create my report

When I use the BI administrator tool, they've asked us to build a physical layer, then the BMM layer and the presentation layer. But there is no reference to such terms while creating a data model using the BI publisher tool and so, I'd like to know the difference between creating a report using BI publisher tool and BI administrator tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my perspective, the biggest differences are scalability and access, though this really only scratches the surface.

### Scalability

The OBI business model should be considered more widely than one reporting requirement. A business model can be used by multiple presentation catalogs, and in turn each presentation catalog can by used by many Analyses and Dashboards. So you only have to build the data model once, and it can be reused and added to over time to make a more complete... well, model of the business. This gives you "one version of the truth", with reports all coming from this one data source.

In Publisher, there is the concept of the data model. This is generally built specifically for one report. You then have many data models (perhaps using the same underlying data sources), for your many reports.

### Consumption

Although Publisher reports can be accessed through the browser and interacted with, the interactivity is generally limited and the reports are (as the name suggests) published in PDF or Microsoft Office formats.

With OBI dashboards there as a much greater degree of interactivity with prompts and navigation. Although these can be published through Agents, they are usually considered as consumed through the browser on a self-serve basis, allowing users the flexibility to answer business questions as they arise.